# Unable to SSH into server from outside University network (but it's not stated in sshd_config)

Tags: ubuntu, ssh, server, remote-access

Our Ubuntu server hosting websites does not allow people to SSH into it from IP:s outside the university network but I need to temporarily disable this.

I've looked up how people normally prevent remote logins (ie sshd_config) but this file does not contain any instructions to block remote IP numbers. So I am wondering, where else could someone have set up the access control so that users trying to SSH into the server does not get a response from the server?

I am not exactly proud of asking this but we got a really messy situation and I would really appreciate any suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your machine has a public IP, you need to make sure the SSH port is open in the university's firewall.  Although your local firewall is either disabled or not blocking the port, the port is almost certainty being blocked elsewhere.  If you are staff or faculty, you will need to contact your university's support center.  Otherwise, if you are a student, you will likely have to ask a professor to do so on your behalf.

Comment: The university hasn't (as far as they admit) changed anything so I believe it is related to an update we did 2 weeks ago but where I am unable to get a hold of the person who did it.